# CSS rounded corners and shadow

Tags: html, css, implementation, rounded-corners

I am in this situation:

I have to do rounded corners and shadow for some boxes on web design. So far I do not have all design and I don't know how many boxes I will have.

In this moment I have 2 different sizes on "width" and of course re-sizable on "height".

The question is:

Which technology you suggest to me to use in this situation ?

PS: *Usually I go with css, making 2 or 3 images for boxes with same "width" size*

But now I think:  "**Maybe it is an old style, already**", too many css classes, not automatic ...etc ?

1. Maybe I can use Jquery (js)  -- (which usually i try to avoid because it is kind of heavy not like css, but I have jquery included already ) and should  I ?
2. To use css3, (but problem in IE7/8) ?
3. To use different way ?

What do you think guys, what is the best practice on this stage of implementation ?

**Updated:**

Because I am starting a new project I would like to now the best practice:

I am not stacked or cannot do **this** and I know as well several way/plugins in jquery or CSS3, question was not which plugin or how to hack IE, but "**Should I use js/hacks, in my case?**"

If I use, JS, I will not have pure css/HTML which is faster -- js is heavy  -> MINUS
JS make more dynamically/easier and less HTML/CSS code      --              ->Plus

I would like to have an advice about this stuff

Thanks

etc ...

Comment: JS is no 'heavier' or lighter than CSS. It all depends on what you are doing with it. The key is to make sure the good browsers aren't burden with whatever JS or CSS you are using for IE. Make sure you server your rounded corner JS/CSS/Images only to IE using IE's conditional tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://css3pie.com/ for limited CSS3 support in IE 6-8

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS3 and let IE7 and 8 have square corners. It's the only sane way to go about it. There's all sorts of ways to use images and JS for IE7/8 but having done it more than once, I really suggest not.

Comment: I need a cross-browser design

Comment: that is why I am asking for the best way which works in all browsers the same, I know several, but which one is the best, this was my real question

Comment: The 'best' way isn't a cross browser solution, unfortunately. If you want cross browser, you need to split your logic somewhere. Use CSS3 for all the good browsers, then a combination of JS and images for <= IE8. Personally, I've never found the added complexity and page weight worth it just to get rounded corners in IE. People using old versions of IE are used to a degraded web experience already so won't be upset if there are rounded corners missing.